# Warning: couldn't fetch mysqli_result in ... using result set from $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session

I am getting this error when I try to fetch a row from my results. Here is the code chunk that is producing the error.

```
            $count = 0;
            @ session_start();
            $result = $_SESSION['results'];
            $str = "";

            while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && $count<= 15){

                //do something;
                $count++;
           }
```

Here is the code chunk that makes the query, and stores the result into the session.

```
$mysql = new MySQLInterface();
$result = $mysql->run_query($query);

       if($result === false){

            //echo "result is boolean and false";
       }else{
            $count = 0;
            while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && $count<= 15){

                //do stuff
                $count++;
            }
           @ session_start();
           $_SESSION['results'] = $result;
       }
```

In this test case, there is 18 rows returned from the initial results. In the first use of the results, I use 16 of the 18 rows, then store it into the session. Later, I pull the result from the session and try to get the remaining 2 rows, and thats when the error is thrown.

Does storing the results in the session cause this error? Or do I need to do something different when trying to pull rows after storing the results? I am also using AJAX when trying to access the results a second time, I dont know if that affects it or not.

Any thoughts as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a MYSQLI command on the session. Even though you can "store" the `$result` object into the session, it is serialized when you do, meaning it retains the information, but not the whole set of functions and the like.

You could achieve something similar by iterating through the results, putting them into an array, then storing the array in the session. Then you can easily iterate through the results using a `foreach` or `for` loop.

```
session_start();
$result = $mysql->run_query($query);
if($result === false)
{
    //echo "result is boolean and false";
}
else
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $_SESSION['results'][] = $row;
    }
}
```

Then to display the data:

```
$myStart=0;
for($i=$myStart;$i<$myStart+15;$i++)
{
    echo $row['index_you_want']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['query'] = "SELECT * FROM table";`, That would run if using `mysqli_query($_SESSION['query']);`

Comment: @DarylGill Good lord, really? I would have bet that the mysqli_query() required the connection object and the like, which can't be serialized into a session and still function?

Comment: @user2947268 Yes the spare `[]` will append a new element to the end of the array - meaning it makes a nice index.

Comment: If not specified, the link will be auto appended to the query according to the last successful query

Comment: I am getting this error on this line: $_SESSION['results'][] = $row;
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array. When trying to store into session, says I cant use type mysqli_result.